# NxN matrix of 1s and 0s

Tags: algorithm

I am having a problem with task
Im given NxN matrix with only 1s and 0s . In each step i generate random 1 in a row and a column of this 1 is closed.  I need to find a minimum number of changes 0 to 1s to be sure that  every row will be able to have one 1.
For example

00

00

I need 2 changes to become

10

01

Or

000

110

000

I  need 3 changes to make

110

110

001

so i can chose first or second 1 in first row. First or second in second row depanding on firsts row chose and 3rd 1 in 3rd row.

Comment: Could you post the original problem text, I couldn't understand the point!

Comment: We have got n workers and n jobs. 1 in i row in j column means that worker i can do job j. 0 otherwise. Each worker choose random job he can do and do it. If worker cant find a job he can do beacouse its already taken he doesnt work. We dont want no worker to dont work. We can train them to do any job for 1coin. What is the least ammoutn of coins we have to spend to make all workers always work no matter of their decisions.

Comment: I guess a little modification of Hungarian algorithm will help.

Comment: Can you say anything more? I cant figure it out

Comment: You say you need the minimum numbers of changes so that there is a `1` in every row (and every column, I suppose). In your example (000,110,000) you say at least 3 changes are needed, but I think only 2 are needed, because matrix (100,110,001) also satisfies the condition.

Comment: When there is a row full of zeros (like two such in your second example), does that mean there is a job that no worker can do, or there is a worker that cannot do any jobs?

Answer (score 2):

Consider your problem as a bipartite graph where we have workers on the left, jobs on the right, and edges if a worker can do a job.

Then compute the maximum matching of workers with jobs (e.g. with [the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)).

If the matching is of size x, then we have successfully paired x workers with x jobs.  We then need to spend n-x money to train the unmatched workers to do the unmatched jobs.